# Dockerized NodeJS container app monitoring its own allocated CPU usage

Tags: node.js, docker, cpu-usage

I want my containerized NodeJS app to be able to track its own CPU usage but don't find a way of doing it (all I found is to monitor the host cores usage).
I don't want to use docker stats inside the container because it would need to run it in privilege mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using:

- [`@adobe/cgroup-metrics`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@adobe/cgroup-metrics)
- CPU count gist (function getCpuLimits()): https://github.com/xiaoxiaojx/get_cpus_length/blob/master/index.js

  ```
  const cgroup = require('@adobe/cgroup-metrics');
  const delay = ms => new Promise(_ => setTimeout(_, ms));

  // **COPY PASTE HERE THE GIST FUNCTIONS**

  const run = async () => {
    const cpu = cgroup.cpu;
    const cpuacct_usage = await cpu.usage();

    // Wait 1s
    await delay(1000);

    const cpuacct_usage2 = await cpu.usage();

    const calculateUsage = await cpu.calculateUsage(cpuacct_usage, cpuacct_usage2);

    console.log('calculatedUsage', calculateUsage / getCpuLimits());

    return run();
  };

  run();
  ```